# How to show a variable of node in page template

Tags: nodes

I have created a content type with some fields in Drupal 7. It output in node.tpl.php of course. But I wonder if I want to display some fields somewhere within the page.tpl.php, how to go about it. e.g. output a content types' field in the header/footer in page.tpl.php or anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This question is more or less a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074485/drupal-7-how-to-render-custom-field. But I'd rather see the answer and question here on Drupal.stackexchange.com.*

This goes into your `template.php` or in a module included file.

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['VAR_NAME'] = '';
  // Get the object and do some other checks based on what you need.
  if (($node = menu_get_object()) && $node->type) {
    // Generate a render array for the node.
    $view = node_view($node);
    // "Create" a new variable for the page.tpl.php.
    // This will expose $VAR_NAME in the page template.
    // You will most likely have to clear your cache.
    $vars['VAR_NAME'] = drupal_render($view['FIELD_NAME']);
  }
}
```

And then in your page.tpl.php:

```
HTML
<?php print $VAR_NAME; ?>
HTML
```

You might also have to hide the field in your node template, if you don't want to print the field twice. Check at [hide()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/hide/7) for that.

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I think in the page.tpl.php have to place the `HTML
<?php if (!empty($VAR_NAME)){print $VAR_NAME;} ?>
HTML` else when when you browse other pages, it will display `Notice: Undefined variable: VAR_NAME in include()..`

Comment: You can also set a default value of an empty string. See the update in my answer.

Comment: Great! I wonder if I were to print node's orginal fields like nid, title. How to go about it then. e.g In node.tpl.php I wrote this and it works `<?php print $node->nid; ?>` , what about in template.tpl.php, how should I write, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Which template file are you asking about? `page.tpl.php`? `html.tpl.php`? In `page.tpl.php`, you can access the `$node` as you do in `node.tpl.php` (`print $node->nid;`). In `html.tpl.php`, you'll have to do something like I did in my answer, but in `XXX_preprocess_html()`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I can access to $node in page.tpl.php just as I do in node.tpl.php for some default fields